# Windows 10 DHCP Client doesn't work

Tags: networking, windows-10, dhcp

I'm experiencing a problem with all my Windows 10 clients, once a while they lose their ip address. This problem happends at Windows startup or also after some time.
The symptomp is the tipical DHCP error, the computer get a generic ip address like 169.254.x.x without gateway and dns.

Usually I can slap a bandaid on this with:

- one *or more* reboots
- dhcp client service restart (sometimes it cannot stop and I have to reboot)
- ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew (sometimes the interface is locked and I have to reboot)
- assign a static ip.

But it will happends again.

At first I thought that is was a DHCP server trouble because I found this problem in my company, but recently I got the same problem also in my personal notebook and in another one. I got this problem with wifi and also with ethernet cable, so I can exclude that it is connected to a single driver, and a single dhcp server. The communal thingh is the operative system, but it doesn't happend on all clients.

Did you find this problem? How can I definitely solve?

Comment: Are the company machines and your personal system by any chance installed with the same VPN client to be able to work from home ? I have seen similar issues with VPN clients in the past if the VPN client wasn't 100% compatible with the newer OS. A VPN client sits quite low-level in the TCP stack (firewall/driver level) and could potentially cause this if it is not specifically designed and tested for this OS.

Comment: No, the two machines are not connected by domain or software. Moreover I experienced the same problem in another computer of my friend. What really I cannot understand is why I could not find informations about this problem if it is really a Windows 10 bug.

Comment: I am a sysadmin in a large company. Have over 3000 Windows 10 machines in the domain. About 300 running standalone. All of them running on DHCP, about 20% with a fixed ip reservation, the others dynamic. I can't say I have ever seen this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check your event viewer for errors first.

Then check your dhcp server, try to add reservations for the computers see if they lose ip by time.

Mostly you need to check " A Record " on the DNS and make sure it's authenticating for new lease if it's not you will need to do it manually by deleting it and re-adding it, and try to add a reverse DNS, also make sure to check the PTR Record on the dns too.

Also be sure your DHCP Is authoritative and it's reachable on the network .